# RVM is not working in ZSH

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm, zsh

I'd like to try out the ZSH shell on my Mac, but I also do a lot of Ruby and Rails development, so I use RVM quite a bit too. The problem is that I can't seem to get RVM to work in ZSH, and it's working fine in the default Bash shell:

```
> zsh
> rvm 1.9.2
> ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [universal-darwin10.0]
> which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```

I can definitely confirm that RVM is installed, as well as ruby 1.9.2 under RVM; I use it all the time in Bash. Running an `rvm list` in ZSH shows this, interestingly:

```
rvm rubies

   ruby-1.8.7-p302 [ x86_64 ]
=> ruby-1.9.2-p0 [ x86_64 ]
```

This is happening on both my iMac and MacBook Pro. I am using OS X 10.6.6 on both, ZSH 4.3.9 on the iMac (4.3.10 on the laptop). Nothing fancy like oh-my-zsh just yet.

I tried looking at the documentation on RVM's [website](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/integration/zsh/), but nothing helped me there.

Answer (score 300, accepted):

Do you have this line in your **~/.zshrc**?

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Comment: Hahaha, totally forgot about that simple thing. Now I'm annoyed at my stubbornness for not coming here sooner. Thank you :).

Comment: You are welcome. It happens sometime :) One useful thing I did to keep my old settings:  "source ~/.profile" and "source ~/.bash_profile" in my ~/.zshrc . It also keep my .zshrc a bit cleaner.

Comment: I found when I used oh-my-zsh to customise zsh it added a bunch of paths to .zshrc that it took from my existing shell -- this included paths added by rvm under bash.

Comment: @intellidiot Do I still need `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting` in `.zshrc`?

Comment: I spent ages trying to figure this out too, as the line `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"` is in my .zlogin, but I suppose it wasn't using it when opening new terminal windows on my mac (10.7.3, oh my zsh). Adding it to the .zshrc worked for me too but according to this [stackoverflow comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566336/switching-over-to-zsh-breaks-rails-in-command-line#comment12161941_9569219), .zshrc is the wrong place to put this??

Comment: Also, make sure that your path to $HOME/.rvm/bin is before /usr/bin, otherwise you might be calling the the Ruby executable that comes with OS X. You can check the precedence by typing 'where ruby' in ZSH.

Comment: Based on all the votes, I'm kinda glad to see that other people miss simple things like me :)

Comment: For a global rvm install - `[[ -s "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" `

Comment: @PerishableDave That was _exactly_ the problem here. I had to add it before `/usr/bin` because it was too late.

Answer (score 25):

### Note March 2014:

With latest RVM, the following line:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

isn't needed anymore, and it shouldn't be in your `~/.zshrc`.

Documentation has been updated in [RVM documentation with Zsh](http://rvm.io/integration/zsh):

> Make sure in iTerm2 Preferences: **Login shell** option is set (do not use Command option). This is required for RVM to work.
>
> If you are still getting rvm is not a function errors on iTerm, try:
>
> ```
> rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles
> ```

Comment: At least on my install of Arch Linux, the xterm doesn't use a login shell and thus rvm doesn't seem to be set up correctly, even running that command.

Answer (score 4):

**Note November 2014**

The rvm installation instructions warn that .zshrc doesn't include $PATH when setting PATH, thus replacing PATH's contents without regard for what already exists in PATH.

To remedy this I now **append** PATH to have `.rvm/bin` and then **prepend** `$PATH` at the beginning of setting `PATH` on the second line:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting

export PATH=$PATH:"/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/opt/local/bin"
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, I solved using this after "ruby on rails" installation:

```
echo 'if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi' >> ~/.zshrc
```

and

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 1):

I use zsh, and had [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" in my .zshrc file, but was getting a parse error:404.

When I moved that line to the .profile file, the error stopped. It seems it was conflicting with something in my .zshrc file, and perhaps running it in .profile avoided the .zshrc file incompatibility. I haven't been able

Answer (score 1):

I got it working on Manjaro Linux (`zsh`) by adding `source /usr/share/rvm/scripts/rvm` to `$HOME/.zshrc`

Comment: Thank you Alexanderius!  My path was not `"$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"` as previous versions.

Adding `source /usr/share/rvm/scripts/rvm` to `.zshrc` worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04.