# rvm doesn't notify when using a new gemset

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm, zsh

I'm using rvmrc files per project. When I `cd` into my project the terminal/rvm does not indicate that I'm using a new gemset. How do I set it up?

In case it helps: I'm using oh-my-zsh.

Comment: Did you read the [Integration/Zsh](https://rvm.io/integration/zsh/) section in the docs? There's a note at the bottom about oh-my-zsh. Also RVM is supposed to take care of this automatically but this answer might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755538/rvm-is-not-working-in-zsh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it might depend on your project files, basically rvm will not print information about using when the `use` keyword is omitted:

```
rvm 1.9.3     # will be quiet
rvm use 1.9.3 # will print: Using...
```

the same result will be when you put those in `.rvmrc`, also generating new `.rvmrc` with `--rvmrc` will behave the same way:

```
rvm 1.9.3 --rvmrc     # `cd` will be quiet
rvm use 1.9.3 --rvmrc # `cd` will print: Using...
```

Comment: use: `rvm use 1.9.3@app1 --create --rvmrc`